# SLComposeViewController addURL issues iOS7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7

I have a standard facebook and twitter SLComposer that brings up a small saying and also attaches a link to the app on the message using the addURL: function. I'm testing it in iOS7 and whenever I brink up the composer I am immediately taken out of the app and to the attached link address (which in this case is the app store). It's only doing this in iOS7. 6 and under works just like before. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Why the down vote and no explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Try add image for share for preview of the url destination.

If `SLComposeViewController` doesn't have image for preview, it tries to get image from the URL of destination server.

In my project I've found redirection on server to *AppStore* from my server.

Comment: When I do this on Twitter it also attaches the image to the post. Have you tested with Twitter?

Comment: No. I've used it only for Facebook.

Comment: @FábioOliveira: This is just the way Twitter works. Images, or actually their URLs, are part of the tweet. Facebook, on the other hand, treats images as attachments. Thus, this workaround is only feasible if you have a relevant image to attach (Twitter *and* Facebook) and have enough characters left to attach it (just Twitter).

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing something similar, but only when adding URLs that *redirect* to the app store, such as bitly links. Regular links outside the App Store work just fine as do App Store links that are direct (e.g. do not redirect). Does this sound right? I think it's a bug in Apple's plumbing for catching loaded App Store URLs iOS wide...

The URL is fully loaded to generate the preview image that you see in the tweet/facebook.  Reported as [rdar://15228808](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5171819229216768).

Answer (score -1):

The behavior of how the Social Framework works was changed in iOS 7.  In iOS 6 my app would just show a dialog for posting to either Facebook or Twitter regardless of whether my device/simulator had an account setup with the respective service.  In iOS 7 it will only show if I have an account setup.  I think this is based on the method "isAvailableForServiceType:".  Without seeing your code, I can't be sure this is your issue, but my guess is that it might be.

Comment: Can you provide any backup that this is expected behavior and not just a bug? It happens only for App Store links and not other links. Seems like a bug and not a feature to me.

Comment: I think it was actually a bug in iOS 6 since the documentation says that this is the expected behavior: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SLComposeViewController/isAvailableForServiceType:

Comment: This is apparently an open bug at Apple--at least my radar was labeled a dup not closed (expected behavior).